# Password confirmation doesn't match when creating a Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

When I try to set up a Gmail account the form keeps telling me that the passwords don't match, even though I paste them both.  What is the problem?

Comment: are you setting gmail account for a third-party application?
gmail account that has been turned on 2-step verification for your account?

Comment: Don't paste them try writing them

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong in pasting password. At the set-up time of Gmail account you can paste password, and it will work.

In your case I guess, some key has pressed or something else. Just copy your password and paste the same in both tab at once. It should work.

I would suggest that instead of copy-paste, try to write password both time.

If still you face the problem, juts clear cache of your browser and start from fresh.